# How to launch Viewcontroller seperate in TabBar Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

i created an Swift project with an Tab Bar navigation. Following i added an Tab Bar controller to my storyboard an connect all Viewcontroller with that. Now something seems pretty strange. If one of both ViewController cant get any data the other Viewcontroller is slow as well. There is no connection between both. So is there a way to solve this problem?[image: my Storyboard]

Find attached my Storyboard:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If one of both ViewController cant get any data the other Viewcontroller is slow as well. There is no connection between both

The thing about a tab bar controller is that it instantiates *all its children simultaneously*. Thus, you have a navigation controller and its child, and a table view controller, and they *both come into existence at once*. So if one of them slows down the interface, it slows down the interface of the other one.

The solution here is *don't slow down the interface*. It sounds like you are doing something very wrong (perhaps in the `viewDidLoad` of your view controllers?), such as networking or doing heavy calculations on the main thread. Don't. Get all of that work off into a background thread so that it doesn't slow things down. This can be quite tricky; for example, gathering the data for a table view over the network is a hard problem, because you have to show the table, get the data in the background, and then populate the table on the main thread. But that's what you have to do.

Comment: Hi Matt, the reason why one Viewcontroller slows sometimes down is that both try to load data from Firebase depending on a query. If the query cant find any data, it takes a bit longer and because of this delay i asked. Thanks

Comment: "If the query cant find any data, it takes a bit longer" OK, but what I'm saying is, that should not be. Nothing should "take a bit longer" because the whole management of the interface should happen on the main thread but the networking from Firebase should happen on a background thread.